# yeoman creates project in Desktop even though I CD into directory

Tags: yeoman, jhipster

I am having a issue creating a yeoman project. I cd in the directory type `yo` and it says:
[image: yeoman]

Here is it suppose to asked me project name etc and it wants to throw everything on my desktop not the file I cd into. It defaults to `mvn` and I want gradle. I even `npm uninstall -g generator-jhipster`
 and reinstalled it and got the same issue.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `.yo-rc.json` file in a parent directory, Yeoman will load that configuration and generate from that file instead of prompting.  This allows developers to run a `yo` command from any folder in the project and have it apply to the correct files.

To solve this, remove the `.yo-rc.json` from the parent directory, in your case `/Users/drew/Desktop`.

For example, if you are in the directory `/Users/drew/Desktop/new-project` but `/Users/drew/Desktop` has a `.yo-rc.json` inside, Yeoman will change to the parent directory (`Desktop`), load the configuration, and generate the files from that folder instead of the child folder.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your log it's looks like you are running yo in a folder where a *.yo-rc.json* is already existing. Careful under windows the .yo-rc.json can be that is of type hidden and you can't see it in explorer. Because of  an existing *.yo-rc.json* you are not asked anymore for info e.g. project name, build tool etc. My recommendation will be to create a new folder run inside yo command